# Monero Wallet GUI daemon version 0.16 stops syncing blockchain at block 2210016 both on Windows and Mac

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Please let me know if there is an option NOT to upgrade to V 0.17 of monero GUI wallet and continue using v 0.16. I need to run v 0.16 because I can not update firmware of my ledger nano s.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *actually use* Monero you will have to update to v0.17 (which Ledger also supports).

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, but ledger nano s provides monero v 0.17 only on latest firmware 1.6.1 to which I can not upgrade to. Any other way to “actually use” monero through v 0.16 wallet pls?

Comment: Follow the Ledger instructions to update your Ledger firmware: https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002731113

Comment: I understand from the replies (or lack thereof) that there is no way to use the monero GUI daemon V 0.16 to actually send XMR. The monero GUI deamon v 0.16 will not sync the blockchain fully, hence the Monero GUI wallet is currently not usable unless it is updated to v 0.17. If you are using Monero GUI via ledger nano S you need to upgrade to latest ledger firmaware 1.6.1 to download the monero ledger app v.0.17 that will work with monero GUI deamon 0.17. Thanks!

Comment: Correct. If the Ledger Live manager does not provide a prompt for the firmware update, try reinstalling it.